# DB2 Query to retrieve all table names for a given schema

Tags: sql, db2, database-schema

I'm just looking for a simple query to select all the table names for a given schema.

For example, our DB has over 100 tables and I need to find any table that contains the sub-string “CUR”.  I can use the like command once I have all the tables.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```sql
--for DB2/z
    select * from sysibm.systables
    where owner = 'SCHEMA'
    and name like '%CUR%'
    and type = 'T';

--for DB2/LUW
    select * from sysibm.systables
    where CREATOR = 'SCHEMA'
    and name like '%CUR%'
    and type = 'T';
```

This will give you all the tables with `CUR` in them in the `SCHEMA` schema.

See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystablestable.html) for more details on the `SYSIBM.SYSTABLES` table. If you have a look at the navigation pane on the left, you can get all sorts of wonderful DB2 metatdata.

Note that this link is for the mainframe DB2/z. DB2/LUW (the Linux/UNIX/Windows one) has slightly different columns, as per the second query above.

You should examine the IBM docs for your specific variant if you're using neither of those.

Comment: `SQL0206N  "OWNER" is not valid in the context where it is used.  
SQLSTATE=42703`

Comment: @Marius, you may have a different schema in your DB2 variant - this was specific to DB2/z, what we like to call the _real_ DB2 :-) For example, in DB2/LUW, you would use CREATOR. It doesn't change the underlying answer, which is to use `systables`.

Comment: my bad: I am using **DB2/LUW** indeed.

Comment: Only IBM would port a product to a different OS and make it incompatible with the original...

Comment: The 4 platforms of DB2  (LUW, z/OS, i and VSE/VM) are not ports of one another, they have separate code bases and have been developed (moslty) independently. Db2 for i is not even a separate product, but an integral part of the iSeries operating system.  Note that the Liunx (including zLinux), Unix and Windows versions are the same codebase and are the same product.

Comment: For those of you using IBM i, your query will be the following:

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM qsys2.systables
```

Answer (score 31):

```
DB2 LIST TABLES FOR SCHEMA <schema_name>
```

Comment: this option has the benefit of being case insensitive.

Answer (score 28):

On my iSeries I have to run this command from iNavigator:

```
select *
from QSYS2.SYSTABLES
where TABLE_SCHEMA
like 'SCHEMA_NAME'
and TYPE = 'T';
```

Comment: QSYS2.SYSTABLES  was needed to list JD Edwards 9.2 tables on an IBM iSeries.

Answer (score 19):

You should try this:

```
select TABNAME from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'yourschemaname'";
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the DB2 commands (no SQL) there is the possibility of executing

```
db2 LIST TABLES FOR ALL
```

This shows all the tables in all the schemas in the database.

ref: [show all tables in DB2 using the LIST command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765412/show-all-tables-in-db2-using-the-list-command#10679460)

Comment: This is really handy if you don't know the schema that you're looking for, or want to dump a list of all the tables in your database to a file. `db2 "list tables for all" > tables.txt`

Comment: That's what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For **Db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows** (i.e. Db2 LUW) or for **Db2 Warehouse** use the `SYSCAT.TABLES` catalog view. E.g.

```
SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA LIKE '%CUR%' AND TYPE = 'T'
```

Which is a SQL statement that will return all *standard* tables in all schema that contains the substring `CUR`.  From a Db2 command line you could also use a CLP command e.g. `db2 list tables for all | grep CUR` to similar effect

This [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html) describes the columns in [SYSCAT.TABLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html) including the different values for the `TYPE` column.

```
A = Alias
G = Created temporary table
H = Hierarchy table
L = Detached table
N = Nickname
S = Materialized query table
T = Table (untyped)
U = Typed table
V = View (untyped)
W = Typed view
```

Other commonly used catalog views include

```
SYSCAT.COLUMNS      Lists the columns in each table, view and nickname
SYSCAT.VIEWS        Full SQL text for view and materialized query tables
SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE    Column that are in PK, FK or Unique constraints
```

In Db2 LUW it is considered bad practice to use the `SYSIBM` catalog tables  (which the `SYSCAT` catalog views select their data from). They are less consistent as far as column names go, are not quite as easy to use, are not documented and are more likely to change between versions.

This page has a list of all the catalog views [Road map to the catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html)

Also, for a general set of queries against the Db2 catalog (and system functions) you can look at the IBM samples library in the [db-library](https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/tree/master/db_library) section
which includes views to do things like generate (approximate) DDL as well as many other things.

---

For **Db2 for z/OS**, use `SYSIBM.TABLES` which is described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystablestable.html). E.g.

```
SELECT CREATOR, NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES WHERE OWNER LIKE '%CUR%' AND TYPE = 'T'
```

---

For **Db2 for i** (i.e. iSeries aka AS/400) use `QSYS2.SYSTABLES` which is described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcatsystbls.htm)

```
SELECT TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '%CUR%' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'T'
```

---

For **DB2 Server for VSE and VM** use `SYSTEM.SYSCATALOG` which is described here [DB2 Server for VSE and VM SQL Reference](https://www-05.ibm.com/e-business/linkweb/publications/servlet/pbi.wss?CTY=US&FNC=SRX&PBL=SC09-2989-02#%20DB2%20Server%20for%20VSE%20and%20VM%20SQL%20Reference)

```
SELECT CREATOR, TNAME FROM SYSTEM.SYSCATALOG WHERE TABLETYPE = 'R'
```

Comment: Using uncommitted read (e.g by adding `WITH UR` to the end of your query) on catalog queries is generally a good idea to avoid waiting on other applications with uncommitted catalog changes.

Comment: This answer was very helpful for my task of hunting down custom database items. Thank you for going into detail!

Answer (score 4):

```
db2 connect to MY_INSTACE_DB with myuser -- connect to db2    
db2 "select TABNAME from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'mySchema' with ur"
db2 terminate -- end connection
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select name from sysibm.systables 
where name like '%ISP%' 
and type = 'T'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the table names simply by typing LIST TABLES in DB2

Comment: That's not true. `LIST TABLES` results in 0 tables for me. Whereas `LIST TABLES SCHEMAX`results in the 796 tables of that schema. Therefore, `LIST TABLES` does not necessarily show all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution:

```
select tabname as table_name
from syscat.tables
where tabschema = 'schema_name' -- put schema name here
      and type = 'T'
order by tabname
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
select * from syscat.tables
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  name
FROM
  SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
WHERE
    type = 'T'
  AND
    creator = 'MySchema'
  AND
    name LIKE 'book_%';
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no big difference in data.The Major difference is column order
    In list tables schema column will be after table/view column
    In list tables show details schema column will be after column type

Answer (score -1):

IN db2warehouse I found that "owner" doesn't exist, so I describe table syscat.systables and try using CREATOR instead and it works.

```
db2 "select NAME from sysibm.systables where CREATOR = '[SCHEMANAME]'and type = 'T'"
```

Comment: Use SYSCAT.TABLES in Db2 LUW and Db2 Warehouse. It has a TABSCHEMA column

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to include the schema/owner column for the 3 different Db2 platforms HTH