# Db2 recursive query connect by

Tags: sql, db2, recursive-query

I am trying to translate an Oracle query

SELECT name 
FROM emp
START WITH name = 'Goyal'
CONNECT BY PRIOR empid = mgrid

Getting error as unexpected token connect by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was your Db2 database created in Oracle Compatibility mode? If not, you won't have `CONNECT BY` support enabled. You can enable `CONNECT BY` independently of full Oracle support by setting the appropriate bit of the compatibility vector. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052877.html

BTW you should use the SYSCAT catalog views rather than the SYSIBM catalog views 
[DB2 Query to retrieve all table names for a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583963/db2-query-to-retrieve-all-table-names-for-a-given-schema/52322317#52322317)

Answer (score 1):

To find dependencies on an object, you could try `DBMS_UTILITY.GET_DEPENDENCY`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055165.html

If you are just interested in table dependencies (but for all tables), this is just one of a number of examples out on the web  https://datageek.blog/2015/05/07/db2-administrative-sql-cookbook-identifying-dependent-mqts-and-views/

Answer (score 1):

That only ever works when ORACLE compatibility is on. Set it as follows, then rerun the query:

```
$ db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=08
$ db2stop
$ db2start
```