# Get column names and types grouped by column names

Tags: sql, db2

I have IBM DB2 database. I would like to get all column names, types length and scale grouped by table names.

To get all tables from schema XYZ:

```
select name
from SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
where creator = 'XYZ';
```

Now I can get colum descriptions for given table:

```
SELECT NAME, COLTYPE, LENGTH, SCALE
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE TBNAME = 'sometablename'
```

I would like to group it:

```
SELECT NAME, COLTYPE, LENGTH, SCALE
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE TBNAME in (select name from SYSIBM.systables where creator = 'XYZ') 
GROUP BY table_names_from_schema_xyz;
```

How to do it?

Comment: Could you please show how you would like your result to look like? Grouping will not provide the column names etc. so you might want something else - showing an example would help us helping you

Comment: I would like to have list of column names with description (type, length) for each table from given schema.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583963/db2-query-to-retrieve-all-table-names-for-a-given-schema/52322317#52322317

Answer (score 2):

Grouping (in the SQL sense) only makes sense in the context of aggregation functions.
I suspect what you are looking for is the output ordered by table name, then column name, so all columns of the same table are "grouped" together.

This query might work for you.

```
SELECT T.NAME AS TABNAME, C.NAME AS COLNAME, COLTYPE, LENGTH, SCALE
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES T, SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS C
WHERE T.NAME = C.TBNAME
AND CREATOR = 'XYZ'
ORDER BY T.NAME, C.NAME;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why soulution above return non distinct values?

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be answered only from SYSCAT.COLUMNS

```
select tabname, colname, typename, length, scale   
 from syscat.columns
where tabschema = 'XYZ' 
order by tabname, colno
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inner join with ***SYSIBM.systables***,probably the below example should work

```
   select c.colname,
            t.tabname as tables, COLTYPE, LENGTH, SCALE
    from SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS c
    inner join SYSIBM.systables t on 
          t.tabschema = c.tabschema and t.tabname = c.tabname
    where t.type = 'T'
    and t.tabschema = 'XYZ'

    order by c.colname;
```

Comment: This query is invalid and should raise an exception. (GROUP BY issue...)

Comment: Nope, consider the case when the same column name exists in several tables.

Comment: you need only inner join in your sql statement

Comment: Looks much better now!

Comment: Still, you should use SYSCAT not SYSIBM...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583963/db2-query-to-retrieve-all-table-names-for-a-given-schema/52322317#52322317

Comment: @Paul Vemon SYSIBM also works please check it once again