# What is DB2 equivalent of Oracle catalog

Tags: oracle, db2

I need DB2 equivalent of this query . Any help is appreciated. I found few links but its confusing which table to query for db2.

```
select table_name 
from all_catalog 
where TABLE_TYPE = 'CATALOG'
```

https://developer.ibm.com/articles/dm-0411melnyk/

Comment: DB2 doesn't seem to have an exact equivalent of ALL_CATALOG. So you'll need one or more of the views in the QSYS2 schema. [Find out more](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm).

Comment: depends on the Platform and version of Db2...

Comment: Try the answer to "DB2 Query to retrieve all table names for a given schema"  here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322317/9525344

Answer (score 0):

Db2 offers an [Oracle compatibility mode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/c_compat_oracle.html). You can switch on views similar to the [Oracle data dictionary](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/c0054440.html). It includes **ALL_CATALOG**, but I don't have personal experience with it.